# Numerically computing Gaussian integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Given a trivariate Gaussian random variable

$$X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$$

I'm trying to compute the expected values

$$\text{E}\Big[\frac{e^{x_i}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+e^{x_3}}\Big]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3\det\Sigma}}\int_{{\bf R}^3}\frac{e^{x_i}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+e^{x_3}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}$$

for $i=1,2,3$.

I've used several different cubature packages to numerically compute this integral, but for certain values of $\Sigma$ it either fails to converge or it returns garbage output.

Here is an example of a parameter set which causes problems:

\begin{align}
\mu&=(-3.4757907, 4.7485485, 0.7119134)\notag\\\\
\Sigma&=\begin{bmatrix}
0.0336 & -0.0215 & -0.0130 \\ 
-0.0215 & 0.209 & -0.0922 \\ 
-0.0130 & -0.0922 & 0.1558 
\end{bmatrix}\notag
\end{align}

It's not entirely clear why the numerical integration packages are failing, I assumed it was either underflow of the denominator or overflow in the exponentials, but when I set $\Sigma=I$ I'm able to successfully perform the integration, which makes me think it might be something else.

I considered forming the approximation

$$e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+e^{x_3}\approx e^{\max(x)},$$

so that I could push all the terms into a single exponential, but it didn't help.

Obviously if it comes to it I can compute these expected values using Monte Carlo methods, however I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

```
using Cubature

B = 200

mu = [-3.4757907, 4.7485485, 0.7119134]
sigma = [0.0336 -0.0215 -0.0130; -0.0215 0.209 -0.0922; -0.0130 -0.0922 0.1558]

inv_sigma = inv(sigma)
C = sqrt(det(2pi * sigma))

function func1(x)
    a = -0.5 * (x - mu)' * inv_sigma * (x - mu)
    f = exp(x[1] + a) / (C * sum(exp.(x)))
    return(f)
end

function func2(x)
    a = -0.5 * (x - mu)' * inv_sigma * (x - mu)
    f = exp(x[2] + a) / (C * sum(exp.(x)))
    return(f)
end

function func3(x)
    a = -0.5 * (x - mu)' * inv_sigma * (x - mu)
    f = exp(x[3] + a) / (C * sum(exp.(x)))
    return(f)
end

p1 = hcubature(func1, [-B,-B,-B], [B,B,B])[1]
p2 = hcubature(func2, [-B,-B,-B], [B,B,B])[1]
p3 = hcubature(func3, [-B,-B,-B], [B,B,B])[1]
```

Comment: What's the determinant of your $\Sigma$? It seems likely to be rather small.

Comment: @Ian $$\det\Sigma\approx0.00065$$Obviously that's just a constant which pulls out, but does the fact that $\Sigma$ is near singular cause problems in the exponential?

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem for a direct evaluation because it means that your integral is nearly confined to a 2D subspace, and a naive meshing will tend to have relatively poor resolution near the subspace. One way to "precondition" in a sense would be to change coordinates to an eigenbasis of $\Sigma$ (offset by $\mu$, if you like). This will effectively "teach" your integrator that a vicinity of the 2D subspace is where all the action is.

Comment: @Ian, could you explain why changing coordinates to the eigenbasis would help?  My intuition would be that the integral would still be nearly 2D, just now super narrow along one of the coordinate axes.

Comment: It makes it easier to just make the mesh finer around, say, $\tilde{x}_3=0$, rather than having to do the refinement along a tilted plane. Ultimately you need to zoom in around that plane to get good resolution anyway.

Comment: @Ian how do I zoom in around that plane?

Comment: That's just a numerical problem of setting up a non-uniform mesh with higher resolution near the plane.

Comment: Can yoy post your code as that is actually more useful

Comment: @Geronimo ok just posted Julia code.